# VXWorks version.h file errors

Tags: vxworks, mbedtls, wind-river-workbench

I have a project and I have added the mbedTLS 2.28.7 to its dependencies. however after doing so and trying to complile my project, I am getting errors in the VXworks target files such as version.h, objLib.h and handleLibP.h.
The errors are typically like :
WindRiver/vxworks-6.9/target/h/version.h:261: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'char'

I have tried changing the version.h from the mbedTLS to that of VXWorks but still no success.
Can anyone please help me find a solution for this